# Check if program_options were added

Tags: boost

I'm using boost program_options for my command line parameter parsing. 
Is it possible to check if there are added options like the following example ? :

```
namespace po=boost::program_options;
po::options_description base; 
po::options_description sub;

if(sub.size() > 0)
  base.add(sub);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in the source code.
Its possible to get the size from the **options_description Method options()** returning a vector. Described [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/options_description.html#idm45507091092080-bb) at Nr. 7

For example:

```
if (sub.options().size() > 0)
{
  base.add(sub);
}
```